# Is it necessary to use a cryptocurrency to make a payment, using blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I'm documenting in this blockchain world. Basically I would like to make some web application in which a user decides to make a donation, and would like to see who made the donation and to which entity. I have several doubts, the first one:

1-Is it possible to use blockchain using javascript? (can smartcontracts be done in javascript?)

2- If the donation is made using blockchain, is it necessary to use a cryptocurrency? or you can use real money and make the transaction (using some means like paypal)

3- Can real money be transferred by some means such as paypal using blockchain?

Thank you very much, your answers will document me much more

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use blockchain using javascript? (can smartcontracts be done in javascript?)

```
 Every blockchain has a SDK, the part of the software which lets you 
 interact   with the real blockchain( A decentralise ledger). There 
 are  generally two parts in the Blockchain , One is client and one 
 is processor. 

As you must have guessed, Client is the one who sends the transaction, 
This transaction must satisfy certain rules in order to be accepted by 
the transaction processor. If the transaction gets validated by 
transaction processor, The transaction will be added to the block alongwith 
other transactions and this block will then be added to the blockchain. 
Copied to all other nodes (Forks are a different story)

Generally Most blockchains lets you interact with the blockchain through 
ABCI which is just an interface to convert your transaction into 
a format understandable by the blockchain processor.

Some blockchains has their fixed transaction processing logic like Ethereum for 
security and some lets you write your own transaction processing logic like 
Sawtooth, Fabric etc.

Permissioned and some public blockchains like Hyperledger projects and 
cosmos SDK lets you write your own application layer logic for Blockchain, 
So yes, You can write those transactions in Javascript or any other programming 
language, as long as it satisfies the interface.

Public blockchain deals with tokens having real worth. Their transaction logic 
is already fixed, but some of them does provide javascript API's like NEO 
(Not   sure about that)
```

2- If the donation is made using blockchain, is it necessary to use a cryptocurrency? or you can use real money and make the transaction (using some means like paypal)

```
 You can do that and put the donation receipt on Blockchain linked with 
 real identities of people. This way if anybody wants to check who pays 
 how much donation, They can query blockchain for the user address.
```

3- Can real money be transferred by some means such as paypal using blockchain?

```
This can also be done, but this will involve using a crypt exchange,
centralised or decentralise. You can convert the real money into crypto 
of your choice at one end and vice versa at the other hand.
```

Note: This is based on my limited knowledge of Cryptocurrencies. Please consult more people or any professional company before acting on this advice.

Comment: If you use the blockchain to record fiat payments, then there is no guarantee that payment went through without also verifying with both parties involved. If you use the blockchain's native token, then you get all the benefits of a public record and the convenience of cryptographic assurance that the transaction is final.

Comment: I never said that fiat exchanged on Blockchain.

Comment: I was just commenting on recording `"donation receipt on Blockchain linked with 
 real identities of people"`

Comment: ohhkk.. Thanks ..One more thing @yavg .. Price conversion from fiat to crypto and back would introduce volatility .. One can also utilise stable coins ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any protocols offer the possibility to implement their smart contracts in Java Script, but you can build a translator between the two languages which could potentially benefit others in the open source community.

So you want have some engineers do some work for you, in this case build an web application. There are several ways you can get this done, here are some ideas:

a) issue tokens which pays profits based on the success of your new business, you might be able to do this on a protocol that is not tied to any specific crypto or fiat currency.
The users can use an exchange to convert your tokens to their favorite one.

b) approach a private equity or VC fund and get them to pay for it.

c) forget about blockchain, and just pay for the project to your favorite engineers.